# A question about the word λεντιον, lention, (linteum ?) in John 13: 4,5

Tags: greek, john, latin, transliteration

In John 13:4,5 the word λεντιον *lention* is used - translated 'towel' usually. Young, Strong, Thayer and Liddel & Scott all refer to *linteum*, a Latin word.

For Strong and Thayer, see [**Biblehub**](http://biblehub.com/greek/3012.htm).

I am aware of suppositions about the garment being associated with crucifixion and I am not interested in pursuing that. I am only interested in the word itself as used by John. The only *scriptural* reference is the incident of the washing of the disciples' feet.

Is the Greek λεντιον a transliteration of the Latin *linteum* ? Or is λεντιον a Greek word in and of itself, is my query. It interests me if it be the case that John has deliberately used a transliteration or, indeed, has himself transliterated it - as, indeed, he may well have done with *arrhaphos* the garment woven without seam, transliterating the Hebrew *erhabon*.

Neither of these is exact transliterations, however. If *linteum* be Latin and *lention* be its Greek equivalent, it may not be an absolute transliteration, but one in which the word is brought into the language and adapted.

One aspect that interests me is whether one should see a situation where Latin, Greek and Hebrew have been used - *arrhaphos* from *erhabon*, *lention* from *linteum*, - in association with Jesus' passion. Thus, not only is the inscription above him written in Hebrew, Latin and Greek; but the doctrinally important matter of the garments associated is also in those three languages.

So, is *lention* a Greek word, or a Latin word brought into Greek through the usual methods of adaptation, or is it a transliteration ?

Comment: Since, as you pointed out, *lention* is unique in the New Testament and not used in the Septuagint, you will need to search other Greek texts for evidence. The utilitarian context and how Jesus wore it in John 13:4,5 would seem to separate *lention* from words translated as scarf, napkin, and handkerchief. Note that Acts 19:12 uses the term, apron or towel (*simikinthion*), which is also unique to the New Testament and the Septuagint. In parallel, you might also consider searching for the earliest use of the Latin *linteum*. Just some suggestions.

Comment: @Dieter. I do not quite understand your usage of the word "unique".

Comment: @fdb, heh, the English word unique ultimately comes from the Latin word *unicus*, from *unus* "one." There is only one reference to *lention* and one reference to *simikinthion* in the New Testament and the Septuagint.

Answer (score 1):

Linteum is a Latin word meaning “a linen cloth”. It occurs in Latin texts from the earliest Roman authors onwards. The Greek λέντιον occurs only in late authors. It is a loan word from the Latin, not a transliteration, but an adaptation of the Latin word. It is not really clear why the Greeks changed the first vowel from /i/ to /e/.

http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlinteum

http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.43:2:142.LSJ

Answer (score 1):

According to *Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature* Third Edition, the Greek word **λέντιον** is a loan from the Latin word ***linteum****. See the abreviation "Lat. loanw." in the *BDAG* entry:

> **λέντιον, ου, τό** (Lat. loanw.: linteum, also in rabb.; Peripl. Eryth. c. 6; Arrian, Peripl. 4; IMagnMai 116, 34; POxy 929, 10 λίνον καὶ λέντιον; Ostraka II 1611, 1; Hahn 235; 262; 266; GrBar 3:5) ***linen cloth*** Hv 3, 1, 4; ***towel*** **J 13:4f** (Vi. Aesopi I c. 61 of a woman who is preparing to wash another person’s feet: περιζωσαμένη λέντιον).

<sub>────────

*See the [*linteum*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlinteum) entry in *A Latin Dictionary* by Lewis & Short.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Only used in the new testament because linen symbolises the righteousness of God that believers receive by faith. Jesse wiped away their sin (dirt on their feet) using a linen cloth as a symbol of the work of the cross.

Comment: Welcome to SE-BH. Care needs to be taken to answer the question which was actually posed and statements made need to be substantiated by citation of references. Opinions are off-topic. Who is 'Jesse' who used linen cloth ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).